# C++: atomically increment counter variable

Tags: c++, locking

If I have two `std::atomic<int>` counters, `a` and `b` (both only doing increments). What I want to do is increment `a` if it's strictly less than `b`, and return the old value of a. In the presence of multiple threads all trying this operation, can I do it without using locks?

The compare-then-increment sequence requires locking to ensure that `a` is not changed between comparison and increment

Comment: `The compare-then-increment sequence requires locking to ensure that a is not changed between comparison and increment`. For reasonable sized integers on normal platforms, no it doesn't. Why do you think that it does?

Comment: Reopened. The purported duplicate was not a duplicate.

Comment: If both a and b are atomic  compare exchange will not work.  Don't see any option without lock that will work fast and will be lockfree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that `a` and `b` are strictly increasing you can do this using `compare_exchange`. The idea is you load the values of `a` and `b` into locals, compare those locals, and if necessary try to swap local_a+1 into `a` if and only if it still equals its old value (which is exactly what compare_exchange does). If this fails, then someone else has successfully updated `a` so you try again including the comparison.

```
int inc()
{
  // Load a and b into locals.
  int aVal = a.load();
  int bVal = b.load();
  while(aVal < bVal)
  {
    if (a.compare_exchange_weak(aVal, aVal+1))
    {
      // Success! Return the original value of a.
      return aVal;
    }

    // Compare-exchange failed, so reload values and try again.
    // Note that if a compare_exchange fails then `aVal`
    // will already be updated with the new value of `a`
    // so we only need to reload `b`
    bVal = b.load();
  }

  // a >= b so don't do anything
  return -1;
}
```

You can probably tighten up the memory_order of the loads and the compare/exchange but this is the simplest version.

Also note that whilst this has a loop in it, a loop is pretty normal (and in fact required for the *weak* version of compare_exchange) and so shouldn't be a worry - this is due to the fact that for each iteration of the loop at lease *one thread* has managed to perform work hence forward progress of the system as a whole always happens.

This works due to the fact that we'll always have the current value of `a` (compare_exchange will fail if we dont and we'll try again) but we may not always have the latest value of `b` as another thread may increment it whilst we're running. However as `b` only increases having an "old" value of `b` is fine as `b` being old and too low will never cause `a` to increment when it shouldn't.